# How to subscribe to IBM MQTT through RfhUtil

Tags: mqtt, ibm-integration-bus

I am using IBM Integration Bus v10, it comes with builtin MQTT. I want to view existing topics and messages. Can somebody tell me how to subscribe to list and subscribe to topic via RfhUtil v7.5?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the PS tab of RfhUtil. Select your queue manager and click "Get topic names". The topics will be listed as shown below. Select one, enter its name to Topic field, and click subscribe.

[image]

You will get a message saying subscription created.
[image]